# Using a physical network adapter on VMWARE

Tags: networking, vmware, vmware-workstation

I just have a server with 2 PCI and 3 PCIx network adapters (offboard of course) already installed. I´d like to use  them inside the Virtual Machine that VMWare creates...

I read about it, and as long as I know it´s just possible to use a external network adapter if it has an USB connection.

Do you know any way to do it that I`m trying?

It´s for a use in a specific video system which requires different vm´s and network adapters.

Tks a lot.

Lyniker Aoyagui

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to achieve it. First is to use physical interface state replication, which you can enable in Network adapter entry in Hardware tab of your VM. With that it will treat hardware interfaces just as if you've plugged them directly into the VM.

Other way to go about it, and one that doesn't require hardware network adapters, is to utilize quite robust Virtual network editor (Edit->Virtual Network Editor) which should allow you to replicate most networking conditions you will need.